# Clojure - function or cons?

Tags: clojure, fibonacci

OK, a fibonacci function in Clojure:

```
(defn give-fibs []                                                                                                                                                              
    ((fn fib-seq [a b]                                                                                                                                                            
        (cons a (lazy-seq (fib-seq b (+ a b)))))                                                                                                                                   
    0 1))
```

Now, my question is, when I call it like so, I get an error :

```
(take 10 give-fibs)
```

edit, error is - `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to create ISeq from: four_cloj.core$give_fibs`

However, it works when I call:

```
(take 10 (give-fibs))
```

When I check out what's going on, I can't really explain it:

```
(class (give-fibs)) ; clojure.lang.Cons
(class give-fibs)   ; four_cloj.core$give_fibs
```

??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`give-fibs` is just that - the function itself. The concept of a function as a value that can be passed around (for example, as argument to `take`) takes some getting used to, but it's perfectly sensible and normal.

`(give-fibs)` is the result of calling `give-fibs` with no arguments, which is what you want in this context. The result is a list, and each element of a list is a `Cons` object, which is what `class` tells you.

Answer (score 1):

In this expression you don't really call `give-fibs`:

```
 (take 10 give-fibs)
```

you just pass the function itself to `take`. What you want is to actually call `give-fibs` in order to pass result of it to `take`:

```
(take 10 (give-fibs))
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the first element in an s-expression is considered to be in function position, that is to say it will be executed. Therefore `give-fibs` and `(give-fibs)` are different in that the former is the actual function being passed to `take` and the latter is calling that function, and therefore returning the result to be passed to `take`.

Thats why `(class give-fibs)` is a function, and `(class (give-fibs))` is a Cons cell as expected.

Just remember the first var after an opening bracket is in function position and will be executed, and its perfectly valid to pass an unexecuted function to another.